# Particle Animation, cocos2d Warnings/Errors

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, compiler-errors

I am new to the objective c world and have been freshly acquainted with the cocos2d framework. I am trying to build a basic touchEnabled particle animation application that calls the subclass ccParticleMeteor. I am receiving the following compiler error/warnings in my .m and I am unable to reconfigure my code to eliminate these compiler errors. Let me know if any other clarification is needed...Thanks!

```
`conflicting types for '-(BOOL)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSET *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event'
Previous Declaration of '-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event'
conflicting types for '-(BOOL)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSel *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event'
Previous Declaration of '-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event'
'UITouch' may  not respond to '-LocationInView:'

Errors
INVALID INTIALIZER. @ CGPoint touch line
LOCATION UNDECLARED. @ CGPoint point line

`- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
   if( (self=[super init])) {
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
    emitter = [[CCParticleMeteor alloc] init];
  emitter.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"starry1.png"];
               emitter.position = ccp(320, 480);
               [self addChild: emitter];
}
return self;
 }
  -(BOOL) ccTouchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self ccTouchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];  
return YES;
 }
-(BOOL) ccTouchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touch = [myTouch LocationInView:[myTouch view]];
CGPoint point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
emitter.position = ccp(point.x, point.y);
return YES;
```

`

Answer (score 1):

```
`conflicting types for '-(BOOL)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSET *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event'
Previous Declaration of '-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event'
```

This tells you that the method signatures don't match. In this case, it should be:

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

In other words, the "touches" methods don't return BOOL.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I am receiving an error @ line: CGPoint touch, which is 'Invalid initializer' and two warnings @ lines return YES, which are 'return' with a value in function returning void. Any ideas?